# Format ROW automatically

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, conditional-formatting

I used conditional formatting to change the fill color of cells with dates before 31/08/15. But, I wanted to format the whole row, not a single cell.

Here are my settings in Conditional formatting.

[image]

[image]

Kindly suggest tweaks and workarounds, I have searched lots of formulas, but none fits to copy the format to the others cells/row.

Comment: Create a CF rule based on a formula. If that column of dates was column M then something like `=AND($M1>0, $M1<DATE(2015, 8, 31))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jeeped's formula will work, just remember to change the range in the 'Applies to' box to include all the columns in your row:

```
=AND($O2>0, $O2<DATE(2015, 8, 31))
```

Conditional formatting rules manager / Applies to:

```
=$A$2:$O$899
```

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ziqLZ.png  http://i.stack.imgur.com/splqK.png , still does not work.Take a look at pics.

Comment: Try choosing the bottom rule type ("use a formula to determine which cells to format") instead of using "format only cells that contain / cell value less than".

Comment: I don't know what to write in that. What is used for copying format from one cell to whole row..?

Comment: You can use the same formula you used in your previous screenshot i.e. **=AND($N2>0,$N2<TODAY())** Just add it to the bottom rule type instead of the 'format only cells that contain' rule type. In the 'applies to' section you can still use **=$A$2:$O$899**